# Document Internal Class with Sandcastle

Tags: c#, sandcastle, shfb

In my C# project, SHFB is not including a description for internal classes, despite having `<summary></summary>` elements before them. The classes even show up in the classes list, yet the description is blank.

[image]

[image]

I have enabled the visibility for internal members, but cannot figure out how to enable internal classes. Any ideas?

Developing in VS2013 Ultimate, using the latest SHFB build (2014.11.22.0) from NuGet.

( I know some will question why I would want to include documentation for internal members, but it has proven useful for our development team to have a quick reference for the code base. )

Comment: With SHFB 2015.1.12.0 and documentation for "Internal members" enabled I get the class summaries. (NuGet may not have the latest, I got mine from https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB/releases). You might want to check too that the latest XML docs for the assembly in question have been built for the right project configuration.

Comment: I have "Internal Members" enabled. I will check the xml docs and download the newer release of SHFB.

Comment: Updated to 2015.1.12.0. The issue persists.

Comment: Figured it out! I did not have the XML output enabled. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @softwariness, I resolved the issue.

1. Open the "Project Properties"
2. Select the "Build" tag.
3. Under "Output", enable the "XML documentation file:"

[image]